# Autohotkey bind one key to several with random timers

Tags: autohotkey

```
3::
Send {3}
Sleep, 55
Send {4}
Sleep, 64
Send {5}
Return
```

**GOAL**: press 3 = press 345

**BONUS**: random sleep time

This is my first AHK script. My problem is that the output of the script is only 45 (not 345). I guess the script just restarts when it gives itself 3?

Would also appreciate pointers on how to randomize sleepers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$3::                    ; The $ prefix forces the keyboard hook to be used
Send 3
Sleep, % rnd(20,60)    ; make a random delay between two values
Send 4
Sleep, % rnd(60,80)
Send 5
Return

rnd(min,max){
    Random, myVar,% min,% max
return myVar
}
```

Comment: Well explained. Could i call "rnd" & "myVar" what I want?

Comment: Yes, their names can be freely assigned.